# Mysql query for Comma separated values in columns and aslo in search keywords

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one condition in query where I want to search results.
In database there is region column in which region is saved as comma separated.
And user select multiple regions which I get in comma separated format.
How can I compare column value and search values.
I want query in codeigniter.

```
$search_id2 = "01,02,03";

$this->db->select('posting_id,short_desc, doc_last, country');
$this->db->from('abc');
$this->db->like('region', $search_id2);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Do you have the chance to get rid of the comma separated data and to normalize your data instead? If yes, please do that

Comment: Yes, normalize your database first. It will make coding these things easier.

Comment: It's not possible because same column used in different function I cant do changes in database.

Comment: You can try to use the FIND_IN_SET function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Comment: do you want to select those id? if yes. I can answer.

Comment: I got answer I used this for($i=0;$i<$Region_cnt1;$i++)
  {
  $this->db->or_like('CONCAT(",",Region,",")' , $search_id1[$i]);
  }

Answer (score 0):

I just try to answer your problem.
You can use `explode()`

```
$search_id2 = "01,02,03";
$search_id2 = explode(",",$search_id2)
$this->db->select('posting_id,short_desc, doc_last, country');
$this->db->from('abc');
foreach ($search_id2 as $key) {
    $this->db->or_like('region', $key);
}
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: actually that won't work - because if he has region codes with 01,02,03,003,004,005 in his db and you are looking for "01,02,03" you get also those matched with 003

Answer (score 0):

as neodan suggested in the comments you can use `find in set`

something like that should do the job

```
$search_id2 = "01,02,03";
$arrSearchIds = explode(",",$search_id2);

$this->db
    ->select('posting_id,short_desc, doc_last, country')
    ->from('abc')
    ->group_start();

if (count($arrSearchIds) > 0)
{
    foreach($arrSearchIds AS $id)
    {
        $this->db->or_where("find_in_set(".$id.", region)", NULL, false);
    }
}
$this->db->group_end();
$query = $this->db->get();
```